# Mocking in junit spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have one class User. I want to update user id. For that I have added one method and used user dto and mapper class to save from userDto to user.

```
public UserDto userUpdate(@RequestBody UserDto userDto){
 UserActivityService userActivityService = BeanLocator.getBean(UserActivityService.class);
 return userActivityService.updateUser(userDto);
}

In userActivityService.java:

public UserDto updateUser(UserDto userDto){
 User user = mapper.mapUserDto(userDto);  //mapper created inside mapper class
 return mapper.mapUserEntity(userRepository.save(user));
}

Now writing Junit for this method:

@Test
 public void userlist(){
  String userType = "ABC";
  UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
  userDto.setId(1);
  userDto.setName(userType);
  
  User user = new User();
  user.setId(1);
  user.setName(userType);
 
  Mockito.when(mapper.mapUserDto(any())).thenReturn(user);
  Mockito.when(mapper.mapUserEntity(any())).thenReturn(userDto);

  UserDto userDtos = userActivityService.updateUser(userDto);
  Assert.assertNotNull(userDtos);  //userDtos null
  Assert.assertEquals(userType, userDtos.getName());
 
 }
```

But userDtos is coming as null. I have mocked mapper class. Could someone help me in fixing this.

Comment: try adding when(userRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(user);

Comment: @VaibS tried that too. but still userDtos is coming null.

Comment: can you show the complete `service` class ? and test class ? it is better to see how you are injecting mappers into service

Comment: If mapper is bean and in test you start context, then you should use `@MockBean` on it.